# C# Android How do i find an error in my app on a real device

Tags: c#, android

My app keeps crashing on a samsung device, but it works on other mobile brands such as lg , it also works the emulator.

Which tools can I use to find the error, and how do i use them?

Comment: logcat that what u need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to connect the device in debugging mode and check logcat.